# adding dynamic text value in JTextArea

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

I am trying to add dynamic text value which is a string in JTextArea but some how by methodname.add or methodname.addElement is giving me an error. Here is the part of the code what I am trying.

Code:

```
 ipList = new JTextArea();
    ipList.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    ipList.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 18));
    ipList.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(ipList);

    byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
     for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
     {
         ip[3] = (byte)i;
         InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
         String hostName = address.getHostName();
         if (address.isReachable(1000))
         {
              ipList.addElement(address.toString().split("/")[1]+ " "+"Device Name: "+hostName);
              ipList.addElement(address.hostName());
            // System.out.println(address.toString().split("/")[1]+ " "+"Device Name: "+hostName);
            // System.out.println(address.getHostName());
         }
     }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error details in your question.

Comment: for ipList.add(address.hostName()) the error is "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: and for ipList.addElement()) the error is "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (String)"